# Prevent Flex Items from Wrapping in React Native

Tags: reactjs, mobile, react-native, flexbox

I'm having some trouble understanding what's going on with the below flex layout in React Native. In each row, I want each `tileContainer` to take up equal space and not to wrap into the next row. In this example, I want all seven tiles to be on the same row. Why does it keep wrapping?

Also, note how each `tileContainer`'s height does not grow to be the height of the parent. Why is this? I want my `tileContainer` to have the same height as the parent container. I'm assuming this is because the parent has `flexDirection: row`, and therefore the `flex: 1` on the child does not make the height grow, but how would I make the height grow?

```
const Row = (props) => {
  const renderTiles = () => {
    return props.row.map((tile, index) => {
      return (
        <View key={index} style={styles.tileContainer} >
          <Text style={styles.tile} >
            b
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
    })
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.row}>
      {renderTiles()}
    </View>
  )
}

Row.propTypes = {
  row: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue',
    flexWrap: 'nowrap'
  },
  tileContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'red'
  },
  tile: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
})
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

To the second question, if you're putting a View1 inside a View2 with `flexDirection: row`, View 1 is only gonna get it's width with the flex attribute, so you have to define it's height, so in your desired case tileContainer should have: `height: '100%',`